# "Press enter to post" sucks. Who do I see about that?

Tags: bug

"Press enter to post" in comments needs to be cut into itty bitty pieces and buried alive, then the pieces and the didt thrown into a fire, and the ashes mailed to Facebook where "press enter to post" belongs.

Seriously, it makes writing comments really twitchy and annoying and burdensome, forcing re-edits, copy-delete-paste-repost, etc.  That's got to be as much of a burden to the system as it is to me.   And just seems sloppy and unprofessional.

Can't this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

See [this meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63644/163027) which includes a workaround you can configure in your browser to change the behavior.